# Displaying text box based on selection of a select element in google sheets html sidebar

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am trying to make a text field appear and disappear based on the selection of a list box.

Unfortunately, I am not able to do so and box appears without being hidden.

I would appreciate any help in this.

I am putting this as HTML file in google script opening in side bar.

**HTML file**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<script>
  loadSelectList();
  
  function loadSelectList() {
    google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {
      let select = document.createElement("select");
      select.id = "CompNameID";
      select.name = "CompName"; // Added
      select.required = "required";
//      select.setAttribute("onchange", "selected()");
      document.getElementById("CompNM").appendChild(select);
      ar.forEach(function(e, i) {
        let option = document.createElement("option");
        option.value = e;
        option.text = e;
        document.getElementById("CompNameID").appendChild(option);
      });
    }).getCompanyFromSpreadsheet();
  };

  function selected() {
    const value = document.getElementById("select1").value;
    console.log(value);
  }
  $("#CompNameID").change(function() {
    if ($(this).val() == "Other") {
      $('#OtherCompName').show();
      $('#otherField1').attr('required', '');
      $('#otherField1').attr('data-error', 'This field is required.');
    } else {
      $('#OtherCompName').hide();
      $('#otherField1').removeAttr('required');
      $('#otherField1').removeAttr('data-error');
    }
  });
  $("#CompNameID").trigger("change");
</script>

<html>
  <head>
    <base target="_top">
  </head>
  <body>
    <hr /><b>Please fill in the form and hit submit</b><br><hr /><br>
    <form id="myForm" onsubmit="google.script.run.withSuccessHandler(google.script.host.close).paddProject(this)">
      <input type="hidden" name="rowNUM" required="required" value=<?= rawnumber ?>>
      <input type="hidden" name="recID" required="required" value=<?= recordid ?>>
      <input type="hidden" name="TimeStamp" required="required" value=<?= timestamp ?>>
      <label><b>Company:</b></label><br>
      <div id="CompNM" class="dropdown-content"></div><br>
      <div id="OtherCompName" class="otheroption-field">
        <label for="otherField1"><b>Group: Heres One!</b></label>
        <input type="text" id="otherField1">       
      </div><br>
      <label><b>Short Description:</b></label><br>
      <textarea name="ShortDesc" cols="35" rows="1" required="required"></textarea><br><br>
      <label><b>Detail Description:</b></label><br>
      <textarea name="DetailDesc" cols="35" rows="10" required="required"></textarea><br><br>
      <label><b>Notes:</b></label><br>
      <textarea name="Notes" cols="35" rows="10"></textarea><br><br>
      <label><b>MSA Link:</b></label><br>
      <input type="url" name="MSALink"><br>
      <br><br><br>
      <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form><br>
    <input type="button" value="Cancel" onclick="google.script.host.close()" />
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I think that in your script, when `Other` is selected `<div id="OtherCompName"` is shown. When other value except for `Other` is selected, `<div id="OtherCompName"` is hidden. From this situation, I cannot understand about your current issue. So in order to correctly understand about it, can you provide more information of your issue and goal? By the way, can you provide the sample value of `ar` of `withSuccessHandler(function(ar) {`?

Comment: My wish is to make it work in the fashion you explained. When `CompNameID` has value selected "Other" `div 'OtherCompName'` is visible otherwise it is hidden. I intended to write that way but current script is not running that. I am also pulling company name using `function getCompanyFromSpreadsheet() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("ddl");
  return sheet.getRange(1, 15, sheet.getRange("K1").getValue(), 1).getValues(); // Retrieve values and send to Javascript
}
` and it is a list of companies like `Company A, Company B, Other`